# How to check using CLI that a token is a NFT?

Tags: cardano-cli, nft, blockchain

One can check with online tools (described [here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/796/verify-that-token-is-nft/797?noredirect=1#comment1054_797)) if a token is an NFT.

How the same thing can be done using CLI tools (in some sort of a script)?

Answer (score 2):

Since at the moment non-fungible tokens are indivisible in the Cardano network, and they can be sent only along with 1,500,000 lovelace, NFTs can be easily seen querying the "balance" at the destination address with the standard command:

```
cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat payment.addr) --mainnet
```

Moreover, don't miss ***[blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io)*** project. Using it you can query information of a native token on Cardano (consider, you need to provide the string concatenation of the `policy_id` and hex-encoded `asset_name`):

```
curl -H 'project_id: 1234567890' https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/d894897411707efa755a76deb66d26dfd50593f2e70863e1661e98a07370616365636f696e73
```

You'll get the following JSON response:

```
{
  "policy_id": "d894897411707efa755a76deb66d26dfd50593f2e70863e1661e98a0",
  "asset_name": "7370616365636f696e73",
  "fingerprint": "asset1pmmzqf2akudknt05ealtvcvsy7n6wnc9dd03mf",
  "quantity": "50000000",
  "initial_mint_tx_hash": "3cce12c77b9d11d70575320c4f2834b26debb065308fbe43954018fbeb90010d",
  "onchain_metadata": null,
  "metadata": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in script i would do the follow :

1. cardano-cli query utxo --address $address --mainnet > fullUtxo.out
2. tail -n +3 fullUtxo.out | sort -k3 -nr  > balance.out
   while read -r utxo; do
3. tokenAmount=$(awk '{ print $6}' <<< "${utxo}")

if you can take this info from step 3.
you can use it how you prefer.
for example
if tokenAmount = TxOutDatumNone , means you have no Token
if tokenAmount = X (number),you have X tokens from the token in the { print $7}

if you need any further assist, let me know

Answer (score 1):

but i realized you speak for NFT.
then i would do it by blockfrost:

curl -H 'project_id: mainnetb2ZFKeNsfggfDFGHJsdgw4nEhuWhExyfV' 
[https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/{asset}](https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/%7Basset%7D)

```
            [![enter image description here][1]]
```